# Codeigniter $this->lang->load('filename', 'language'); is not working for non default languages

Tags: localization, codeigniter-3, multilingual

I'm using `$this->lang->load();` method to load language file for my multilingual website. This method is work for only custom created language file by me. This method is not work for default language files in Codeigniter/system/language/english folder.

e.i:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // Loading language files.
    $this->lang->load('custom', 'date', 'calendar' 'ar');

}
```

I just need to load `custom_lang.php, date_lang.php, calendar_lang.php` files in CI/application/language/ar/date_lang.php and etc.

But this method loads files from CI/application/language/en/date_lang.php file and etc.

Thats the problem. but this method works fine for custom created lang files. e.i: custom_lang.php.

I overrided default langauge configuration in config.php file by using `$this->config->set_item('language', 'ar');` before that method.

e.i:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->config->set_item('language', 'ar');

    // Loading language files.
    $this->lang->load('custom', 'date', 'calendar', 'ar');

}
```

And then core lang file also switching smoothly. but dunno why this not work without overriding `$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');` this method.

As mentioned in CI documention, This should work without overriding defualt language.

[Codeigniter documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDN75.png)

Comment: Is there a comma ,  missing between 'calendar' and 'ar' ?

Comment: Yeh! but this is only in sample code. In my real code fine.

Comment: I fixed that sample code.

Comment: I would've tried to answer if you didn't try to impersonate me. :)

Comment: OMG! narf :D Hey first of all I'm really sorry for impersonate you. I didn't much mind that. You are so pupular guy related to CI. so when I create stackoverflow account I got instantly remembered your name. Again I'm really sorry.

Comment: Can you help me  to solve this issue. Im really confuced. :)